# How to add extra fields to a django model by extending it?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a django application using Pinax Stripe(https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe). Pinax stripe is a bundled application which has a model called 'Plans'. Now in my application, I want to add some extra fields to the model 'Plans' in my application BUT without modifying the original pinax stripe application.

Something like this:

```
    #models.py
from pinax-stripe.models import Plan

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #write the extra fields here
```

Is there any way I can do it and then register it with admin so i can add data to those fields in admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the `Plan` models and add your own attributes:

```
from pinax-stripe.models import Plan

class MyPlan(Plan):
    # add your attributes
    pass
```

This works like normal inheritance in python, plus your custom attributes are migrated when you run a migration because the original pinax `Plan` is a subclass of `models.Model`.

However, be careful to not use attribute names that already exist in the pinax `Plan` model, since your new model will automatically take all the attibutes from `Plan` and Django cannot write migrations for duplicate fields.

Comment: Thankyou @Moses Since you know about pinax stripe, do you know how can I add a plan to my plans using code maybe a webhook or something?

Comment: @Elisha512 Unfortunately, I have never had reason to use `pinax-stripe`, so I really don't know much about it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subclass `Plan` and add whatever fields / methods you want:

```
from pinax-stripe.models import Plan

class UserProfile(Plan):
    #write the extra fields here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you, use the `OneToOne` relationship [like Django docs recommend to use in the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

```
from pinax-stripe.models import Plan

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    plan = models.OneToOneField(Plan , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #write the extra fields here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download pinax folder from https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe into your app and edit models.py and admin.py files as per your requirement.